# How to display a WordPress notice on create_term action

Tags: admin, terms, notices

I am hijacking [`create_term`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50898/how-to-use-create-term-edit-term-delete-term-actions?rq=1) to do stuff when a new term is created...

```
// Fire the function when new term is created
add_action( 'create_term', 'process_term', 11, 3 );

function process_term($term_id, $tt_id, $taxonomy) {

    if ($taxonomy == 'post_tag') {
        // Do stuff
    }

}
```

By means of experimentation and learning, I'd like `// Do stuff` to include displaying a feedback confirming that we saw a new 'post_tag' term was created.

I have [read](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/50914/39300) that `create_term` does not support echoing anything back to the browser. Indeed, Doing a simple in the function breaks something in display...

```
echo $taxonomy;
```

[image]

In my case, IF the term was created in the admin backend (ie. either in the edit-tags.php Tags section or in the post-new.php or similar Post edit screen), I'd like the feedback to take the form of a WordPress alert notice bar on the subsequent screen.

[image]

"Subsequent" is an interesting question, I suppose, because the edit-tags.php page doesn't refresh to a new page when a term is created on it. And I guess that is the same for post-new.php, sometimes (?). They often update in-situ.

I'd settle for a simple `echo` in order to understand whether doing anything out of `create_term` is possible. But I guess that's what a "notice" really is... you echo out HTML with the notice class, right?

With that in mind, the following code, which places `admin_notices` inside my `create_term` function, does not produce broken displayed code - but it also does not display any notice message at all, suggesting admin_notices isn't even firing...

```
// Fire the function when new term is created
add_action( 'create_term', 'process_term', 11, 3 );

function process_term($term_id, $tt_id, $taxonomy) {

        add_action('admin_notices', 'my_admin_notice');

}



function my_admin_notice() {
    ?>

    <div class="notice notice-success is-dismissible">
        <p>This is a success message.</p>
    </div>

    <?php
}
```

Comment: I was recently trying to accomplish something similar.

Comment: @Mark In my case, turns out I also need to remove an error being thrown in the admin by Ajax when the moved term cannot be found. As well as adding a new notice. So I'm wondering if wp_ajax_add_tag() has a role to play - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/345813/how-to-replace-wp-ajax-add-tag-error-notice-on-create-term

Comment: Sorry about that.  I'd started a comment and got pulled away.  Didn't realize it posted!  Comment was supposed to say that I ended up adding custom admin columns to CPT and tax indicating whether or not some meta had been correctly added to the term.